Google recaptcha token verification does not work when deployed
I have set up google recaptcha to verify the token shared with the backend. So I'm using the site key in the frontend (react application) and the secret key in the dotnet backend to verify the token received
using the url

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=`REDACTED`response=`REDACTED`

and I have registered my domains on the console as well along with localhost.
However, even though the localhost server side verification works when the frontend is run local, it doesn't work when the frontend is deployed.
I keep getting the error "invalid-input-response"
Any idea how I can fix this?
